# Which is the default values for YARN Capacity Queues?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm concerned about 'acl_administer_jobs' and 'acl_submit_applications' properties. I would guess the default is "*" but since a single space " " means no access, I'm not sure about it.

Where can I see the default property values for YARN queues depending on the policies?

Comment: This question is different from the other one. That one ask which is the default queue that YARN use to execute jobs (this is not a default property in the xml config files) while this is asking for default values of queues depending on the policies. They are completely different...

Comment: Fair enough. Have you not found what defaults you are looking for here? https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.5/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at your cluster capacity scheduler properties in file capacity-scheduler.xml  which is generally under /etc/hadoop/

More details about Capacity Scheduler and its properties - https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.3/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html

For default YARN configs (Hadoop 3.0.0) - https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml

For default YARN configs (Hadoop 2.8.3) -  https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.3/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml

Setting `yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.acl_submit_applications` to `empty value` means No access to root queue.
i.e

> yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.acl_submit_applications=

Above property restrict access to `root` queue